# System crashed after using mount and Stuck on tty2 login loop.

Tags: mount, permissions

I was trying to get the rw permission of a file. But I used mount / -o rw,remount in root instead of adding sudo at the front. And after I typed that command. The system crashed, all the commands like cd, ls, are not found or no permission. 
So I try to going into tty2. And I try to open a terminal and login. However, after I type in username and password , the login screen flashed and disappeared and it asked me to type username and password again and again. If I don't do anything, it goes to low graphics mode itself. Anyway to save this laptop? Didn't back up anything...
Please

Comment: pop will wait after this weekend then reinstall